# Looping an ajax function with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array that is looping and each one of them needs to go through a ajax/php function. However this doesn't seem to be working. Can you show me a correct way of doing this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "data=" + arr[i],
        url: "proxy.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $("#test").html(msg+msg);
        }
    });
}
```

The id "test" needs to contain all the vals gotten from php.

Comment: Kevin B Please respond so i can accept it! Thanks

Comment: One thing to be aware of here, the A in AJAX stands for asynchronous. What this means for you is that the responses from your server might not arrive in the order you sent them out.

Comment: Another issue is, depending on the length of your array, you could be sending out a whole bunch of requests at once, which can also cause a problem on the server. You might want to think about how to throttle your requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html()` replaces the current content with what you pass into it. Instead, you need to add to the content.

```
$("#test").append(msg,"<br />");
```

Comment: Could be write $("#test").append(msg,'<br />') to fit jquery typo

Comment: Ah, yeah i forgot .append could take multiple arguments. Thanks!